# Is the gem 'thredded' compatible with rails 5 api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am currently developing a social media-ish app, and it needs a forum. I wanted to use a gem for the forum side of the app. We are using Rails as a backend API serving json responses to the frontend using Angular.

With that, I've seen the thredded readme, and it seems that it has a view side to it which Rails 5 api clearly lacks. With that, will it still smoothly work with Rails 5 api? Just checking out if someone has tried this out already. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Rails' API mode disables some Rails features to improve the performance for non-html applications. I would be surprised when a gem that depends on views and view helper works in such an environment.

Answer (score 0):

if you go there home page on github https://github.com/thredded/thredded you will see a message that reads

> @glebm glebm Bump Rails to 5.0.1 in spec/gemfiles/rails_5_0.gemfile
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYhnf.png)

that message will change on the next commit

now if what you are asking if they are using action cable. I did not find anything to say that they were.

but they are rails 5 compatible

I hope that this helps